# Tensorflow hyperparameter tuning - metrics for each trial not outputted

Tags: tensorflow, metrics, hyperparameters

I want to tune a hyperparameter in slightly modified `DNNClassifier`. I was able to run the tuning job and it succeeded too but the output does not show the final metrics for each trial. This is what the final output looks like:

```
{
  "completedTrialCount": "2",
  "trials": [
    {
      "trialId": "1",
      "hyperparameters": {
        "myparam": "0.003"
      }
    },
    {
      "trialId": "2",
      "hyperparameters": {
        "myparam": "0.07"
      }
    }
  ],
  "consumedMLUnits": 1.48,
  "isHyperparameterTuningJob": true
}
```

how do I get the final metric for each trial so as to decide which value is the best?

My code looks like this.

My DNNClassifier:

```
    classifier = DNNClassifier(
        feature_columns=feature_columns,
        hidden_units=hu,
        optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr),
        activation_fn=tf.nn.leaky_relu,
        dropout=dr,
        n_classes=2,
        config=self.get_run_config(),
        model_dir=self.model_dir,
        weight_column=weight_column
    )

    tf.contrib.estimator.add_metrics(classifier, compute_metrics)

def compute_metrics(labels, predictions):
    return {'my-roc-auc': tf.metrics.auc(labels, predictions)}
```

The hyperparameters spec is as follows.

```
trainingInput:
  hyperparameters:
    hyperparameterMetricTag: my-roc-auc
    maxTrials: 2
    enableTrialEarlyStopping: True
    params:
      - parameterName: myparam
        type: DISCRETE
        discreteValues:
          - 0.0001
          - 0.0005
          - 0.001
          - 0.003
          - 0.005
          - 0.007
          - 0.01
          - 0.03
          - 0.05
          - 0.07
          - 0.1
```

I mostly followed the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/using-hyperparameter-tuning#add_your_hyperparameter_metric_to_the_graph_summary).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. The issue was

```
tf.contrib.estimator.add_metrics(classifier, compute_metrics)
```

It should have been

```
classifier = tf.contrib.estimator.add_metrics(classifier, compute_metrics)
```